# Internet Explorer .htacces issue with friendly URLs

Tags: .htaccess, internet-explorer, friendly-url, modx

So I built a MODx site that is hosted on site5. In the system settings I enabled friendly URLs and everything works fine on FF, Chrome, and Safari but for some reason it isn't working properly in Internet Explorer.

For instance, normally when you go to "example.com" you get there and everything loads fine. Then you click on "Contact" and that takes you to "example.com/contact" which works up until that point even in Internet Explorer. It's when you click another page, let's say "Blog", while you're still on the previous page so instead of going to "example.com/blog" it takes you to "example.com/contact/blog" and you end up at a big obnoxious 404.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about:
http://acegrease.com/image001.png

Here's what my .htaccess file looks like:

```
# MODX supports Friendly URLs via this .htaccess file. You must serve web
# pages via Apache with mod_rewrite to use this functionality, and you must
# change the file name from ht.access to .htaccess.
#
# Make sure RewriteBase points to the directory where you installed MODX.
# E.g., "/modx" if your installation is in a "modx" subdirectory.
#
# You may choose to make your URLs non-case-sensitive by adding a NC directive
# to your rule: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


# Rewrite www.domain.com -> domain.com -- used with SEO Strict URLs plugin
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^acegrease\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://acegrease.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# or for the opposite domain.com -> www.domain.com use the following
# DO NOT USE BOTH
#
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example-domain-please-change\.com [NC]
#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example-domain-please-change.com/$1 [R=301,L]



# Rewrite secure requests properly to prevent SSL cert warnings, e.g. prevent 
# https://www.domain.com when your cert only allows https://secure.domain.com
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443
#RewriteRule (.*) https://example-domain-please-change.com/$1 [R=301,L]



# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]



# Make sure .htc files are served with the proper MIME type, which is critical
# for XP SP2. Un-comment if your host allows htaccess MIME type overrides.

#AddType text/x-component .htc



# If your server is not already configured as such, the following directive
# should be uncommented in order to set PHP's register_globals option to OFF.
# This closes a major security hole that is abused by most XSS (cross-site
# scripting) attacks. For more information: http://php.net/register_globals
#
# To verify that this option has been set to OFF, open the Manager and choose
# Reports -> System Info and then click the phpinfo() link. Do a Find on Page
# for "register_globals". The Local Value should be OFF. If the Master Value
# is OFF then you do not need this directive here.
#
# IF REGISTER_GLOBALS DIRECTIVE CAUSES 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERRORS :
#
# Your server does not allow PHP directives to be set via .htaccess. In that
# case you must make this change in your php.ini file instead. If you are
# using a commercial web host, contact the administrators for assistance in
# doing this. Not all servers allow local php.ini files, and they should
# include all PHP configurations (not just this one), or you will effectively
# reset everything to PHP defaults. Consult www.php.net for more detailed
# information about setting PHP directives.

#php_flag register_globals Off



# For servers that support output compression, you should pick up a bit of
# speed by un-commenting the following lines.

#php_flag zlib.output_compression On
#php_value zlib.output_compression_level 5



# The following directives stop screen flicker in IE on CSS rollovers. If
# needed, un-comment the following rules. When they're in place, you may have
# to do a force-refresh in order to see changes in your designs.

#ExpiresActive On
#ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
#ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
#ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
#BrowserMatch "MSIE" brokenvary=1
#BrowserMatch "Mozilla/4.[0-9]{2}" brokenvary=1
#BrowserMatch "Opera" !brokenvary
#SetEnvIf brokenvary 1 force-no-vary
```

Comment: Currently I've turned friendly URLs back off so that the client could view the pages without running into this issue. Let me know if you want me to turn them back on if you need to see the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have:

```
<base href="[[!++site_url]]">
```

In the templates  section?

If that's already there you could try what I did. I ran into this problem on a clients site - It was on the navigation menu, I got around it by forcing all links to be absolute rather than relative. That is, if I wanted to link to a page with id 10,  instead of putting:

`[[~10]]`

I used:

```
[[~10?scheme=`abs`]]
```

Hope this helps.